# FaceDetectionListener in Android not runs if PreviewCallback is implemented too

Tags: java, android, camera

I am doing an Android application to use camera. I implemented facedetectionlistener to camera focus in faces zones and runs fine, but when I also implemented PreviewCallback to do some processing tasks facedetectionlistenes stops running. Why? How can i solve it?

Is possible that camera object only can have one callback associated?

Thanks